# Firebase find users with username using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to find users by their username value in firebase. I have searched around and tried the following:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('username').equalTo("testUsername").once('value', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val().username);
  });
});
```

Heres how my database looks:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "Hr9AFYHgOBZKkBqCjST789NrTJX2" : {
      "profileData" : {
        "description" : "This is a description",
        "username" : "testUsername"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone see what im doing wrong here? and how to retrieve the username?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('username').equalTo("testUsername").once('value').then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val().username);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `orderByChild()` call you need to specify the entire path to the value you want to order/filter on. Since `username` is nested under `profileData`, that is:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('profileData/username').equalTo("testUsername").once('value', function (snapshot) {
  ...
```

Note that you'll also need to define your index for the nested property, so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "profileData/username"
    }
  }
}
```